# what's the difference between hibernate-mapping PUBLIC and hibernate-configuration PUBLIC in hibernate configuration file？

Tags: xml, hibernate

In Eclipse I produce the hbm.xml file automatically using db browser. When I deploy my project there is the following exception printed on the console：

Could not parse mapping document from resource. hbm.xml.

When I modified the `hibernate-configuration PUBLIC` in hbm.xml to be `hibernate-mapping PUBLIC` there is no exception. Why? What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

```
hibernate-mapping PUBLIC( For domain object mapping files only)
```

The mapping document is an XML document having  as the root element [which](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_mapping_files.htm) contains all the  elements,those who creates tables for you domain objects

```
hibernate-configuration PUBLIC(for configuration file only )
```

is used to provide the information [which](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_configuration.htm) is necessary for making database connections. The mapping details for mapping the domain objects to the database tables are also a part of Hibernate `configuration` file.